# Encryption of private key in centralized PKI with bouncycastle

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, pki

I'm writing a CMP server and I have a problem.
It is used in a centralized PKI where the RA send a private key with the associated certificate to the server, that we have to relay to the CMP client.

The problem is that I can't find how we are supposed to encrypt the private key to send it to the client and for him to be able to decrypt it.
Do we only rely on the security of https, because it sounds wrong ?
Did I miss something in the CRMF RFC ?

A solution would be, I guess, to generate a temporary keypair from the client and use it for encryption/decryption but is sounds more like a hack than the way to do it properly.

It is easy to do when the client is the one generating his keypair, but in this specific case, everything is generated by our OpenTrust RA.

Comment: Are you *really* sure that RA generates private key? For example, CRMF message, in particular, has NO fields to store private key.

Comment: You don't have to send the private key to the client. There is something seriously wrong here. Either it's your private key, which you are supposed to keep private, or it's the client's private key, which *he* is supposed to keep private. If two parties have the same private key the entire point of PKI is destroyed.

Comment: The way it works is that a server will give a CN and a password to the CMP that will check to a LDAP that it has the right to request an enrollment.
Once it's done, OpenTrust will generate a private key and a certificate for the client. It's done by OT because legally we have to sequestrate a copy of the private key.

Answer (score 3):

PKCS#12 can be used to distribute private keys from an RA to the various clients. We have used a hardware USB token for this purpose. Data on the USB token can only be decrypted by the software on the client side (using a pre-shared secret).
If you don't want to use hardware tokens, the only option you have is to use a pre-shared secret (communicated via some out of band/out of channel means) and use that symmetric key to distribute the private key and transmit it over HTTPS. Also make sure your HTTPS is configured to use at least AES-256.